# How to do method chaining for an interface?

Tags: go, interface, method-chaining, nullptr

I would like to do something like `obj.WithX().WithY().WithZ()`. `obj` can have different types, which is why I am using an interface.

Unfortunately `obj` can also be `nil`. In that case my method chaining will panic, because I am calling a method on a nil-interface and go does not know which method to call.

[minimal reproducible example here](https://go.dev/play/p/UN9o5qHwTF2)

How can I still use method-chaining with an object that may be `nil`?

- Is there a way that I can provide a default implementation for `WithX()` and the other functions?
- I also thought about a pattern where each of the property functions returns a function, but that seems overly complicated

```
obj.WithX().WithY()    // of type func() myInterface
obj.WithX().WithY()()  // now I got the actual object.
```

Comment: If you want to use method chaining, you simply cannot return nil.

Comment: Don't return nil. Instead return an object that stays it is not valid.

Comment: Make your question self-contained by including the relevant code. Only link to a Go playground as a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are *mostly* correct, but really you just can't return an *untyped* nil.

```
func new(someParam bool) inter {
    // more complicated. May return A, B or nil
    if someParam {
        return &A{}
    }
    var b *B
    return b // which is nil, but of a type that implements the interface
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/EE2k8VYJL9T

So basically you just need a "default" type, which can be nil, which still implements the interface.

Comment: Either way is fine I think, this depends on the method being valid with a `nil` receiver, vs ensuring that the returned value is not `nil`. A detail worth understanding is that the returned value here is not actually `nil` which is why it works. `b` is a typed `nil`, but the returned `iter` is a non-nil interface value.